# Where do you report a product vulnerability?

Tags: vulnerability

There is a bug in a widely used payment processing SAAS provider that I have tried reporting to them.  And if they had showed it to an engineer they would have understood.  I don't have time to keep dealing with their less than useful support staff.

Where can I responsibly report this vulnerability so that they can take over the explaining it to them role?

Comment: Tell them you will disclose the bug publicly in 90 days (or whatever timeframe you deem appropriate) and they should get in touch with you.

Comment: @MechMK1 That is certainly a good way, though I wouldn't recommend it without at least a couple of caveats (legal ramifications may depend on location, and how OP got to know about the issue).

Comment: This question has been asked [many times before](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+report+a+vulnerability)

Comment: Agree, this is a duplicate question that already has many answers here.